# Efficient way of Retrieving data for multiple rows simultaneously

Tags: database, hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee

When we tried to retrieve data for a arraylist, we are iterating each row and then we are using fetch query.is there any other iteration row in hibernate template or sql

```
for (RequestObjRel reqObjRel : requestObjRelList) {

    String sqlQuery = "from Ce where cerId = '"
            + reqObjRel.getCed()
            + "' and trbr = "
            + reqObjRel.getCNbr();
    List<Certificate> certDetailList = dao
            .retrieveTableData(sqlQuery);
}
```

I could not find efficient way to retrieve data

Comment: get the data in a single query...

Comment: @MitchWheat how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html) query that uses the `IN` clause and thus fetch multiple objects with one query. Something like:

```
from Foo foo where foo.id in (:fooIds)
```

Then you set the parameter on the `Query` object: `query.setParameter("fooIds", listOfIds);`

Comment: Thanks but can be pass more than one  parameter.

Comment: the parameter is a `List` containing all the ids of your objects

Comment: hmm..but if we composite primary key than what are available options

Comment: one last question how the above query will changed then

Comment: the query itself won't. It's just the list you pass that will contain the composite ids

Comment: can you help me in eloborating answer.i have already put one [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769690/hibernate-hql-query-how-to-set-a-collection-as-a-named-parameter-of-a-query-wi) regarding this