# Hibernate HQL Query : How to set a Collection as a named parameter of a Query with composite key?

Tags: sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

Given the following HQL Query:

from Foo foo where foo.id in (:fooIds)

but here i have composite key in the Id ex we have two PK1 and pk2 as Id's.

How can we implement this query..

how can i pass both paramets in setparameters function of query

My question is similar this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570229/hibernate-hql-query-how-to-set-a-collection-as-a-named-parameter-of-a-query)

*HBM file containing composite key is present below*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
    <composite-id>
        <key-property name="foo1" column="FOO1" type="java.lang.String" length="36"/>
        <key-property name="foo2" column="FOO2" type="java.lang.Short" />       
    </composite-id>

    <property name="EffectiveDt" type="java.sql.Date"  column="EFFECTIVE_DT" />             
    <property name="effectiveTypeCd" type="java.lang.String" column="CERT_EFF_TYPE_CD" />
    <property name="statusCd" type="java.lang.String" column="CERT_STATUS_CD" />


</class>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a composite id? Do you have a separate class representing the composite-id or do you have 2 fields in Foo and you want to search using them in your query?
Posting you Foo class would help!

Comment: we have 2 field in the the Foo class and we want to search using them.there is no separate class for composite ID

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure you can use `in` in this case. One thing you can do is to build the query manually with something like

```
 String hqlQuery = "from Foo foo where "
 boolean first = true;
 for( ID id : fooids ) {
     if( first ) {
          hqlQuery += "foo.id = ?";
          first = false;
     } else {
          hqlQuery += " OR foo.id = ?";
     }
  }

  Query q = em.createQuery(hqlQuery);
  int position = 0;
  for( ID id : fooids ) {
      q.setParameter(position, id);
      position++;
  }
```

You might want to double check the code, as I'm writing it here, so there's a big chance there's a typo or two.

Comment: so here your fooids will contain both primary key